# PCA recognition OpenCV 2.3

Tags: android, opencv, pca

I have a problem with opencv2.3 and android 2.2: I have a set of 10 image where i take the face and with the functin PCACompute and PCAProjet, i compute the subspace of PCA and projet the image into this subspace.
So, i have the Mat with eigenvectors, the Mat with mean value and the Mat result.
My question is: how i can perform the face recognition with a new image? What data i must compare? Eigenvalues, eigenvectors?
I hope that someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply calculate euclidian distance between new image and trained images
http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_5/page_5.html

Comment: Hi bluekid, i know this step, but the euclidean distance must be calculated between two eigenvectors, two mean or what??  thaks for your reply :D

Comment: Eigenface consists of two phases: learning and recognition. In the learning phase, you give eigenface one or more face images for each person you want it to recognize. These images are called the training images. In the recognition phase, when you give eigenface a face image, it responds by telling you which training image is "closest" to the new face image. ( read the article )